# Laravel where orwhere

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this function:

```
public function indexo2returneditems(Request $request)
    {
        $per_page = $request->per_page;
        $sortBy = $request->sort_by;
        $orderBy = $request->order_by;
        $dateFrom = $request->dateFrom;
        $dateTo = $request->dateTo;

    return response()->json([
        'ok1' => O2order::where([['result', '=', 'Failed'], ['status', '=', 'Failed']])
            ->whereDate('finisheddate', '<=', $dateTo)
            ->whereDate('finisheddate', '>=', $dateFrom)
            ->paginate($per_page),
        'ok2' => O2order::where('deviceexchangedto', '<>', '')
            ->whereDate('finisheddate', '<=', $dateTo)
            ->whereDate('finisheddate', '>=', $dateFrom)
            ->paginate($per_page),
        'not_ok' => O2order::where('result', '=', 'Failed')
            ->where('status', '=', 'Failed')
            ->orWhere('deviceexchangedto', '<>', '')
            ->whereDate('datecreated', '<=', $dateTo)
            ->whereDate('datecreated', '>=', $dateFrom)
            ->paginate($per_page),
    ], 200);
}
```

Ok1 and Ok2 are working fine, but when I join them together it's not working

What am I doing wrong, what can I do?

Comment: Do you mean `not_ok` is the broken version?

Comment: What do you mean, when you join them together?

Comment: With `its not working` you mean an error or empty result? Where did you join them? Can you put your code that doesn't work and the result?

Comment: They are only examples, ok1 and ok2 are working fine. Its only API to vue. When I change date laravel send me correct values. Only this not_ok send me  wrong values, not error. But for example when i pick only one day in vue correct values are only 3 record but laravel send me 200.

Comment: @Dusan If you just want to combine the result of `ok1` and `ok2` then rather use `$ok1->union($ok2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use where function in this

try this

```
$not_ok = O2order::where(function($query){
                   $query->where([['result', '=', 'Failed'], ['status', '=', 'Failed']])
                         ->orWhere('deviceexchangedto', '<>', '');
                                   })
        ->whereDate('datecreated', '<=', $dateTo)
        ->whereDate('datecreated', '>=', $dateFrom)
        ->paginate($per_page);
```

because when you are using **orWhere** it simply put or in your query so your query became something like this

```
select * form table1 where a = 'condition 1' and b = '2' or b = '3' and date1 = date(now())
```

while what you want is

```
select * form table1 where a = 'condition 1' and (b = '2' or b = '3') and date1 = date(now())
```